# how drop some dictionary key-value from a dataframe column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with two columns `time` and `dic` in `dic` column i want to drop `1:00` and `4:00`. how to do that with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dic={'time':[1685660515,1685689306],
     'dic':[{"0:00":"2", "1:00":"1","2:00":"0","4:00":"0"},
            {"0:00": "0", "1:00": "0", "2:00":"3","4:00":"0" }]}
df= pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

| time | dic |
| --- | --- |
| 1685660515 | "0:00": "2", "1:00": "1", "2:00": "0","4:00":"0" |
| 1685689306 | "0:00": "0", "1:00": "0", "2:00":3","4:00":"0" |

Comment: please provide a reproducible input, it's currently unclear whether you have strings, dictionaries, etc. and difficult to replicate.

Comment: If you really have dictionaries, you have to loop over the rows and over the keys to `del` or `pop` them. Something like: `for d in df['dic']: for k in d: if k in {'9:00', '15:00'}: del d[k]`

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not reproducible, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), and have you tried the duplicate and my suggestion above?

Comment: I have edited the quation as you said please check it once Thank you.@mozway

Comment: Then what I suggested above [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Czm.png)

Comment: getting this error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` @mozway

Comment: Yes, replace `for k in d` by `for k in list(d)`